# Using aliases with nohup

Tags: bash, unix, alias, nohup

Why doesn't the following work?

```
$ alias sayHello='/bin/echo "Hello world!"'
$ sayHello 
    Hello world!
$ nohup sayHello
    nohup: appending output to `nohup.out'
    nohup: cannot run command `sayHello': No such file or directory
```

(the reason I ask this question is because I've aliased my `perl` and `python` to different perl/python binaries which were optimized for my own purposes;  however, nohup gives me troubles if I don't supply full path to my perl/python binaries)

Comment: try `eval nohup sayHello` (I'll be surprised if it works though). Good luck.

Comment: How about put the nohup command in the alias:

`alias sayHello='nohup /bin/echo "Hello world"'`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because the shell doesn't pass aliases on to child processes (except when you use $() or ``).

$ alias sayHello='/bin/echo "Hello world!"'

Now an alias is known in this shell process, which is fine but only works in this one shell process.

```
$ sayHello 

Hello world!
```

Since you said "sayHello" in the same shell it worked.

```
$ nohup sayHello
```

Here, a program "nohup" is being started as a child process. Therefore, it will not receive the aliases.
Then it starts the child process "sayHello" - which isn't found.

For your specific problem, it's best to make the new "perl" and "python" look like the normal ones as much as possible. I'd suggest to set the search path.

In your `~/.bash_profile` add

```
export PATH="/my/shiny/interpreters/bin:${PATH}"
```

Then re-login.

Since this is an environment variable, it *will* be passed to all the child processes, be they shells or not - it should now work very often.

Comment: "Therefore, it will not receive the aliases." I was thinking, the child process, like `(echo "TheAlias=$(alias sayHello;sayHello)")&wait` fails, it seems that the alias is not applied but is present; I wonder if there could have some way to apply the alias that do exist?

Answer (score 7):

For bash: Try doing nohup '`your_alias`'. It works for me. I don't know why back quote is not shown. Put your alias within back quotes.

Answer (score 5):

With bash, you can invoke a subshell interactively using the `-i` option. This will source your `.bashrc` as well as enable the `expand_aliases` shell option. Granted, this will only work if your *alias* is defined in your `.bashrc` which is the convention.

**Bash manpage:**

> If the `-i` option is present, the shell is **interactive**.
>
> **expand_aliases**: If set, aliases are expanded as described above under ALIASES. This option is *enabled by default* for interactive shells.
>
> When an interactive shell that is not a login shell is started, bash reads and executes commands from `/etc/bash.bashrc` and `~/.bashrc`, if these files exist.

---

```
$ nohup bash -ci 'sayHello'
```

Comment: This answer applies for a more general case, and should work for all aliases.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [Aliases](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Aliases.html) section of the Bash manual, it says

> The first word of each simple command, if unquoted, is checked to see
>   if it has an alias.

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem like `bash` has anything like `zsh`'s [global aliases](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-alias), which are expanded in any position.