# run a function or alias set in bashrc, or profile through nohup

Tags: shell, nohup, bash

My question is similar to this one. 
[Using aliases with nohup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9301531/using-aliases-with-nohup)

I took a lot of time customizing a function that I included in my .bashrc 
I'd like it to run with nohup, because I'd like to run a command several times in this fashion.

```
for i in `cat mylist`; do nohup myfunction $i 'mycommand' & done
```

Any tips?

Comment: Unrelated, but the correct way to iterate over a file is `while read -r i; do ...; done < mylist`

Comment: This not duplicate, other quesiton wanted to use functions inside bash script, I'm asking about ow to do it at the cli.

Comment: Script or command line, it doesn't matter. `nohup` expects its argument to be an executable file, not a shell function. That makes this a duplicate of the other question.

Comment: @kmassada You can wrap it in a shell script. that's the best solution if you need this to work. Think the question is good although maybe duplicate. However, you got your solution... :)

Comment: got you chepner and @hek2mgl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`nohup` will not work with functions. You need to create a shell script which wraps and executes the function. The shell script then you can run with `nohup`

Like this:

*test.sh*

```
#!/bin/bash
function hello_world {
    echo "hello $1, $2"
}

# call function 
hello_world "$1" "$2"
```

`chmod +x test.sh` and then call it in your `for` loop:

```
for i in `cat mylist`; do 
    nohup ./test.sh $i 'mycommand' & 
done
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with functions (not aliases) by `nohup`ing a `bash -c` (which is essentially the same as running an external bash script).

In order for this to work, you need to mark your function as `exported`:

```
# define the function
echo_args() {
  printf '<%s> ' "$@"
  printf "\n"
}
# mark it as exported
declare -fx echo_args

# run it with nohup
nohup bash -c 'echo_args "$@"' bash_ "an argument" "another argument"
```

The argument `bash_` to `nohup` provides a "name" for the `bash -c` subshell; that is, it becomes the value of `$0` in the subshell. It will be prepended to error messages (if any), so I try to use something meaningful.

Comment: Looks nice :).. Didn't know about `declare -fx`